# how to get distinct values from a list in Sharepoint 2010

Tags: 2010

I'm building a tab based on a list
in the list i have something like this:
Title    Categories
Bread  Food
Mazda Car
VW     Car
Egg     Food

How can i get a unique value in the category field?
I tried using marcs method from: http://sympmarc.com/2007/10/23/eliminating-duplicates-in-data-view-web-parts/ 
But its not working with SP 2010 sharepoint designer...
Any ideas and thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

If you need to do this in pure XSL you can use [xsl:key](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/el_key.asp) to pick out the unique values in your XML data. The key element is often used with the [Muenchian method](http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html) to render the groupings

If you are coding in C# then I'm not aware of any [CAML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms467521.aspx) support for Distinct queries. So you'll need to retrieve the full data set and "distinct" it yourself. .Net has some support for this in [DataTable.ToTable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wec2b2e6.aspx)

Answer (score -1):

SharePoint 2010 gives you the ability to create unique list columns OOB. So you can edit the properties of the Categories field and mark it to contain unique values.

Comment: problem solved used xsl:key :)